# Format Google Sheet Iframe to remove horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html

I would like to correctly size my iframe to remove the need for the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the embed. I'd like the embedded sheet to display B35:T:85 and have included this in my code. Is there a way to zoom the iframe out and remove the need for the horizontal scroll bar?

```
<iframe 
src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ95yN1oJxvAtt-le0bH4llfO8N1TTH8PP-9-xx9A83DJoCn8YKwXIkuHSipqGcR31XMQvbHRlrZUX7/pubhtml?gid=1881116956&range=B31:T85&chrome=false&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false"width="100%"height="1000px"seamless frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Site Link: https://hidden-homes-a5c997-0490d1c88ec2911d413.webflow.io/dashboards/analytics

Answer (score 1):

You used the `app-main-layout-wrapper` class twice before the frame, which you have to delete and you must remove `card-3` after `app-main-layout-wrapper`class before `iframe` because  `card-3` class had width:1000px and remove `html-embed-4` before `iframe` element because it had `width:900px`

Comment: I've removed these classes but the content still doesn't scale correctly. https://hidden-homes-a5c997-0490d1c88ec2911d413.webflow.io/dashboards/analytics-copy